# Eclipse XML format on MacOS is disabled

Tags: xml, eclipse, macos, format

How can I format XML files using:

- CMD + SHIFT + F
- Source -> Format?

It seems that it is disabled.

[image]

Comment: With which editor (right-clicking _Open With_ shows what?) of which version? It works for me with both editors, the _XML Editor_ from Eclipse WTP and the _Generic Text Editor_ with XML support from Wild Web Developer. By the way, the dark theme plugin you have installed patches Eclipse via loadtime weaving which can cause issues and slow down Eclipse (the vendor of this plugin tries to cheat the open source license of Eclipse by doing so). If you don't like the built-in themes, there are other dark themes that are more ergonomic and don't do this.

Comment: @howlger I have installed this plugin for Dark Theme cause this is the most downloaded plugin on Eclipse, and I really like the style. But if you can suggest another one, I'll try it to see if I'll like it.

Comment: Well, it is also easy to cheat on download numbers as well. ;) I personally use the built-in light theme for ergonomic reasons. You might try the [Eclipse Spectrum Theme](https://github.com/AObuchow/Eclipse-Spectrum-Theme).

Comment: looks nice, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My pom.xml was opened with "Maven Pom Editor"

To change it you need to go on:

Window > Preferences > General > Editors > File Associations

and you need to chang pom.xml associated editor.

[image]

Comment: _Maven POM Editor_ supports _Source > Format_ (Ctrl+Shift+F) via Wild Web Developer (in the preferences as _XML (Wild Web Developer) > Formatting_). It seems you are using an outdated Eclipse.

Comment: Eclipse version: 2022-12 (4.26.0)

Comment: Formatting can be found in the right-click menu _Source > Format_, but your right, it's missing in the _Source_ main menu. See [WWD issue #533](https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper/issues/533).